# Set websocket origin to localhost javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, cors

I have server with doamin example.com. When user loads page on this server, it uses websocket client on javascrip to connect another websocket server. 
Another server uses CORS. So user can't connect to another server with websocket, becouse header Origin: example.com. But with Origin:localhost it can connect.
Is it possible to set Origin: localhost when use javascript to connect with websocket?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways i think should be ok

1. You can on the "another websocket server" add the code:

`res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");`

if you could not do that,you can use another way.

2. Reverse Proxy perhaps is a choice,but i think it's not a simple way.
   You can use nginx to implement Reverse Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The Origin header is added by the browser when the request is created. You can't specify a custom value nor change it with javascript. Why do you say that user can't connect to the server? Websockets supports cross domain. If the server is checking the Origin it would be easier change the code to allow example.com also.

Comment: I cant change another server

Comment: Well, if the server only allows local connections and you're not the owner of the server, you won't reach it from outside (maybe using hacking tools you can change the headers for developing purpose).